# How to achieve reverse localization (user input) on Laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, input, localization

> Laravel's localization features provide a convenient way to retrieve strings in various languages, allowing to easily support multiple languages within the application.

At this point I'm using the function `trans()` and related that ships with Laravel, to translate (localize) the user interface (output) of my application, as one would usually do with a default setup. As how this strategy works, we are translating *english* keys into another language. It is clear that *keys* need not to be in any particular language, and they don't even need to be readable text, that we just keep them readable for sake of software maintainability and comply a standard, since the programmatic keywords are in *english*.

My question is if there's a well known way to accurately translate user input in a selected language back to the base language (let's say *english*).

An example of this would be letting the user to write certain keywords or expressions in their language as input, and get them into a base language.

Currently, I would do something like this:

```
// Dummy Sample Code I

$foreignInput = 'lunes';

$translatedToBase = trans("input.days.$foreignInput");

dd($translatedToBase); // "monday"

// lang/es/input.php

[
// ...
  'days' => [
    'lunes' => 'monday',
    // ...
  ],
// ...
]
```

I would also do something like this:

```
// Dummy Sample Code II

$foreignInput = 'lun';

$translatedToBase = trans("input.days.$foreignInput");

dd($translatedToBase); // "mon"

// lang/es/input.php

[
// ...
  'days' => [
    'lun' => 'mon',
    // ...
  ],
// ...
]
```

This would perfectly work for the purpose, however, it feels *hacky* (unsafe, little reliable, hard to maintain and counter-intuitive) and I wonder if there's a package of better way to achieve this. I could even require not using `trans()`, that's fine for me.

I understand there may be lots of options, so suggestions are welcome as long as I can keep some constrains:

- Also please note that in this example I used a weekday name, but I'd not limit the solution to a datetime context.
- Plus, I'm seeking to rely on the translation to be strict, this means that I'm expecting it to be deterministic, reason I'm putting aside a live translation external service.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what this functionality is and what the UI might look like?  I suspect the answer to your problem doesn't involve the inversing of translations.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I find it hard to explain (as you see), since I did not yet implement this in any way. But you have an example of the [live application here](https://demo.timegrid.io)

Comment: Suppose I want the user to provide a list of days on text, and later I'd parse those by php. So I'd like the user to write the weekdays in his language.

Comment: Maybe these screens help: [english input](https://snag.gy/0KQ6mG.jpg) and [spanish input](https://snag.gy/c7pNa9.jpg).

Comment: The best way to solve your problem is by using database translation. Inverse translation in laravel would mean searching the translated files in order to find the right match. With good enough database structure you can query the inverse results easily

Comment: Thanks, looks like a possible approach. There are some good packages for that, but as far as I saw I'd still need to hack the intended use to achieve this. Maybe I can write an `rtrans()` function, and that would be it.

Comment: @alariva I would still suggest a database but i can write an answer with `rtrans()` if you want to skip the database solution

Comment: The database solution is valid but pretty straightforward by using a package. I keep that in mind. Also considering that Laravel 5.4 ships with some new translation capabilities. The rtrans() would be still cleaner than my first approach and really easy to implement. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't structure the language files the way you suggested. It's a subversion of Laravel's organisation to have shifting keys that have the same value throughout translations, and they would have to be specifically populated for reverse translation because they'd be too hard to use for normal translation. I'd much rather stick to the normal Laravel structure:

```
// lang/en/input.php

[
// ...
  'days' => [
    'monday' => 'Monday',
    // ...
  ],
// ...
];

// lang/es/input.php

[
// ...
  'days' => [
    'monday' => 'lunes',
    // ...
  ],
// ...
]

// lang/de/input.php

[
// ...
  'days' => [
    'monday' => 'Montag',
    // ...
  ],
// ...
]
```

Here's an object capable of processing the reverse translation:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use RecursiveArrayIterator;
use RecursiveIteratorIterator;

class ReverseTranslator
{
    protected $languageGroups = [];

    protected function loadGroups($locale)
    {
        // Iterate through all available groups and store
        $languagePath = resource_path("lang/{$locale}/");
        $languageGroups = array_map(function ($file) use ($languagePath) {
            return str_replace([$languagePath, '.php'], '', $file);
        }, File::glob($languagePath.'*.php'));

        $this->languageGroups[$locale] = $languageGroups;

        return $languageGroups;
    }

    protected function lowercase($value)
    {
        return is_array($value) ? array_map([$this, 'lowercase'], $value) : Str::lower($value);
    }

    protected function arraySearchRecursive($search, array $array, $mode = 'value', $return = false) {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
        foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
            if ($search == $value) {
                $keys = [];
                for ($i = $iterator->getDepth()-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                    $keys[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($i)->key();
                }
                $keys[] = $key;
                return implode('.', $keys);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function search($foreign, $group, $locale = 'en')
    {
        // Load all strings for group in current language
        $groupStrings = trans($group);

        // Recursive and case-insensitive search
        return $this->arraySearchRecursive($this->lowercase($foreign), $this->lowercase($groupStrings));
    }

    public function get($foreign, $group = null, $locale = 'en')
    {
        if (!$group) {
            if (!isset($this->languageGroups[$locale])) {
                $this->loadGroups($locale);
            }
            foreach ($this->languageGroups[$locale] as $group) {
                $key = $this->search($foreign, $group, $locale);
                if ($key !== false) {
                    return trans("{$group}.{$key}", [], null, $locale);
                }
            }
            // Failed to match -- return original string
            return $foreign;
        }

        $key = $this->search($foreign, $group, $locale);
        if ($key !== false) {
            return trans("{$group}.{$key}", [], null, $locale);
        }

        // Failed to match -- return original string
        return $foreign;
    }
}
```

Put this on your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` inside the `register` method:

```
$this->app->bind('reverse-translator', function () {
    return new ReverseTranslator();
});
```

Then you could build a Facade to access your object more literally.

```
class ReverseTranslator extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'reverse-translator';
    }
}
```

Now you can write your helper like so (using the Facade, not the object itself):

```
function rtrans($foreign, $group = null, $locale = 'en') {
    return ReverseTranslator::get($foreign, $group, $locale);
}
```

Then usage would simple:

```
rtrans('lunes'); // "Monday"
rtrans('lunes', 'input'); // "Monday", quicker
rtrans('lunes', 'input.days'); // "Monday", quickest
rtrans('lunes', 'other'); // "lunes", because of wrong group
rtrans('lunes', null, 'de'); // "Montag"
```

Note:

- I've made the search case-insensitive to be a little easier to use, and because case is relevant and should be considered in translation arrays (see "Monday" on `lang/en/input.php`).
- Obviously it's much more efficient to know which file you want to load and search, so if you know your translating weekdays, you'd pass `'days'` as your group. But if you don't know, then you'd have to iterate through all available language files, which could become costly depending on how often you do it and how many files you have.
- Maybe the ideal solution would be to extend the default Laravel translator to give it "reverse translation" capabilities, instead of using a stand-alone object like above, but for the sake of clarity it has been isolated.

I hope this is a good starting point. Buena suerte!

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer. I will post back as soon as I can try it out!

Comment: Almost on it! It works, but I need to highlight a few details: I have changed the helper to instantiate the class object like so: `return with(new App\TG\Support\ReverseTranslator)->get($foreign, $group, $locale);` And as result I'm getting the full key path like this: `rtrans('martes'); // returns "input.days.tuesday"`

Comment: [Here my test code approach](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/commit/42cc0bf7c2338ff07e35efc529c36ce2f40fafc8)

Comment: Right now it nows what language key your foreign string refers to, but it can't find the English equivalent. I suspect this is because the default locale in the code I gave you is `en`, but your English folder is actually `en_US`.

Comment: I thought the same. I've tried changing the defaults to `en_US` but the behavior is still the same. No clue.

Comment: My bad, I was missing adding the `input.php` into the `en_US` dir. Also reversed default locale to `en` and still works neatly.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. As for the helper, bear in mind that creating a new object each time you invoke the function is not the best scenario, in my opinion. Since the object stores the available language strings you should only instantiate it once, which is why I suggested a Facade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades

Comment: I agree, but then the method should be static which is not possible since it accesses `$this`. It should be then a singleton.

Comment: Yes, well, we're speaking of the same thing. I originally suggested a Facade, which is why I invoked the `get` method as if it was static, even though it never was. I've added code you can copy/paste in order to create that Facade easily. It's up to you ;)

Comment: Wow! Thanks! What do you think about taking it to a package? I think it would be really useful.

Comment: If you want to build it, be my guest. If it's not directly related to your business logic, having it as a package is a good idea to me. I don't have time to maintain such a package myself, though...

Comment: I could do it, in that case it would of course carry your authorship on credits.